# An Implicit rule without Prerequisites in Makefile

Tags: makefile

directory structure：

```
src
├── Makefile
├── grpc
│   ├── grpc_demo5_client.go
└── └── grpc_demo5_server.go
```

Makefile：

```
groc/test: groc/grpc_demo5_client.go

groc/%:
    echo $@ " - " $^
```

Output result:

```
echo groc/grpc_demo5_client.go " - " 
groc/grpc_demo5_client.go  - 
echo groc/test " - " groc/grpc_demo5_client.go
groc/test  -  groc/grpc_demo5_client.go
```

[documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-versus-Implicit)

> An implicit rule can apply to any target that matches its pattern,
> but it does apply only when the target has no recipe otherwise specified,
> and only when the prerequisites can be found.

I think that the file `groc/grpc_demo5_client.go` is not a target.
My question is why `echo groc/grpc_demo5_client.go " - "`  and `groc/grpc_demo5_client.go  -`  appear in Output result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile) from the same source as your documentation:

```
When a target is a file, it needs to be recompiled or relinked if any of its
prerequisites change. In addition, any prerequisites that are themselves automatically
generated should be updated first.
```

Since `groc/test` depends on `groc/grpc_demo5_client.go`, `groc/grpc_demo5_client.go` becomes a target which must itself be generated. Without this kind of recursive behavior,  `make` would not be nearly as useful.

In [still more documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Rules), it says:

```
If none of the explicit rules for a target has a recipe, then make searches for
an applicable implicit rule to find one
```

Your first rule has no recipe, so the recipe from the second rule is used for `groc/grpc_demo5_client.go`.

But maybe your problem is that there's typos in your Makefile, and `groc` should be `grpc`. Try:

```
grpc/test: grpc/grpc_demo5_client.go

grpc/%:
    echo $@ " - " $^
```